# Will Telltale's The Walking Dead require online access to play or just to download or both?

Tags: the-walking-dead-season-one

I may not have online access on the future, but I have it for the moment and I was thinking about dowwnloading the game from the PSN store. I played the demo, and everytime I went to start it it kept trying to sign me in. I didn't have to play the demo signed in, but I will have to play the full game signed in? Does the online access help save my progress in one episode to track my progress in the next?

Comment: I played it on the pc, and at the end it gave statistics about how many people had choose what option, whether this is optional depending if you had a net connection, i don't know.

Comment: @Taz: I played the entirety of episodes 2 and 3 offline (on Xbox 360, at least), and I still got the stats at the end of each episode. So, that data must be downloaded ahead of time at some point.

Comment: @cloudymusic ha, how strange. Maybe you're right. its prefilled data that was gather in the beta testing or something... Kinda a let down if it is. Now what I do doesn't really change the stats.

Answer (score 3):

After downloading it, you need to be online to activate it. When it's activated, no internet connection will be required.

Comment: I realize that this is a stale question (Telltale is out of business...) but I would also like to add that if you have the Telltale games on Steam, you need to be online to obtain the achievements. I replayed multiple episodes since I had been in offline mode on the initial playthrough and achievements did not pop. I think that the reason for this is just how the Telltale account system interfaces with the Steam 'presentation' of the games.